# Is there any Firefox addon to convert text to UPPERCASE or lowercase

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, text-editing

Is there any Firefox addon to convert a bit of selected text (in text fields), to "UPPER CASE", "lower case", "Proper Case", and "Sentence case"?

This is useful when writing email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [Leet Key](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/770) does that.

Answer (score 1):

Try [TitleCase](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/titlecase/); this will do sentence (proper) case as well as title case, upper case, and lower case.

> Transform strings into Title Case, Proper Case, Start Case, Camel
>   Case, Upper Case, and Lower Case. You have 2 ways to change text.
>   Either by right clicking on the field and changing the case or by
>   highlighting and only changing what you highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Casey Case Converter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9920)?

The author of the add-on hasn't updated all descriptions, but from the release notes:

> Version 1.4 — June 29, 2009 — 6 KB
>
> - Proper case improved to support sentences with !?. and larger chunks of text.
> - UPPERcase added
> - lowercase added

It works all the way up to firefox 3.5.

Comment: It can only convert to "Proper Case"

Comment: Um..it also does upper case and lower case too.  I installed it to check!

Comment: THIS WAS CONVERTED TO UPPER CASE BY CASEY CASE

Comment: The author of the add-on just hasn't updated the description but From the release notes:

Version 1.4 — June 29, 2009 — 6 KB

- Proper case improved to support sentences with !?. and larger chunks of text.
- UPPERcase added
- lowercase added

Answer (score 0):

[decaps](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9439) should fit your bill of selecting text and switching between upper, lower and sentence case.

Problem with it currently is that it hasn't been updated for Firefox versions later than 3.0.*